Difficulty with a scaling argument
I am trying to make sense of an argument in this paper, "Fracture strength: Stress concentration, extreme value statistics and the fate of the Weibull distribution".
The paper deals with how cracks of different lengths $w$ are distributed in a body. The argument  I fail to get is mathematical in nature, does not require any undrstanding of cracking behaviour, please just replace "crack" with "random variable" to get full generality.
The argument I cannot wrap me head around goes as following, it is fully contained in a small portion of text, just before and after equation (4):
1. "<...> take $\exp [−h(w)]$ to be probability that the volume element
$V_0$ does not contain any crack longer than $w$  <...>"
2. "<...> If the defect size (crack length) distribution is a power law with exponent $\gamma$ <...>"
3. <...> Then $h(w) ∼ w^{-\gamma}$ <...>"
How could this be?
Say the random variable (crack lengths) is distributed according to a power law, say Pareto distribution (with scale parameter $x_{min}$)
$$w ∼ (\gamma -1) w_{min}^{-\gamma -1} x^{\gamma} .$$
Then the Cumulative Distribution Function (CDF) equals
$$ 1 - \left(\frac{w_{min}}{w}\right)^{-\gamma - 1} .$$
According to the definition in the list above, item (1), well that is the definition of the CDF itself is it not?
So I get
$$ \exp [−h(w)] = 1 - \frac{w_{min}}{w}^{-\gamma - 1} $$ and hence
$$ −h(w) = \log \left(1 - \left(\frac{w_{min}}{w}\right)^{-\gamma - 1}\right) $$
Now as I am interested in the behaviour for large values of $w$ I could use the approximation $ \log(1+x) \sim x$ for "small" $x$
$$ −h(w) = \log \left(1 - \frac{w_{min}}{w}^{-\gamma - 1}\right) \sim -\left(\frac{x_{min}}{w}\right)^{-\gamma - 1}$$
so it would turn out $h(w) ∼ w^{\gamma +1}$
not $h(w) ∼ w^{-\gamma}$ as claimed in the paper.

ok I think I see the beginning of my error, "the probability that the volume element 0 does not contain any crack longer than " might not be the CDF of the crack length distribution...

I think the distribution $\sim w^{-\gamma}$ is meant to be the distribution of lengths assuming there is one crack. To get to the probability of having no cracks $> w$, you need to sum over all possible numbers of cracks. I'm trying to write up an answer to show this.

yes indeed, literally looking at the possibility

I believe the "crack length distribution" $\sim w^\gamma$ is meant to be the probability that a single crack will have length $<w$. In other words, there are two subtle things here: (a) we are conditioning on having only one crack, and (b) the word "distribution" here means a CDF and not a PDF (if we interpret it as a PDF, I also run into the issue you point out in your question, so I am pretty sure it is meant to be a CDF). Let's call that
$$
P(\ell < w | 1) = k w^{-\gamma}
$$
ie, the probability of the crack having length $\ell$ less than $w$, given that there is $1$ crack, is proportional to $w^{-\gamma}$. $k$ is a normalization constant here.
If we have $N$ cracks, assuming that they don't interact, then the probability that the $1$st crack has probability $w_1$, $2$nd crack has probability $w_2$, etc, is
$$
P(\ell_1 < N, \ell_2 < N, \cdots \ell_N < w | N) = \frac{k^N}{N!}w^{-N \gamma}
$$
where the factor of $1/N!$ comes because the cracks are unordered.
Now we don't know how many cracks there are, so we should consider all possible numbers of cracks, and sum the results. Or,
\begin{eqnarray}
P(all<W) &=& P(0 < W| 0 ) + P(w < W | 1) + P(w_1, w_2 < W | 2) + \cdots \\
&=& 1 + k w^{-\gamma} + \frac{k^2}{2!}  w^{-2\gamma} + \cdots + \frac{k^N}{N!} w^{-N\gamma} + \cdots \\
&=& e^{h(w)} 
\end{eqnarray}
where $h(w) = k w^{-\gamma} $.
I'm not sure why they define $P=e^{-h}$ instead of $P=e^{h}$, but at the level of precision in the paper where there is not an equals sign relating $h$ to $w^{-\gamma}$, I think this likely boils down to a matter of convention. (In other words, if we defined $h(w) = - k w^{-\gamma}$ above, then we'd get $P = e^{-h}$). I assume this makes more sense in the full context in which they are working.

yes thank you, sorry I took your time and I realised my error after writing the question down, happens to me all the time.

No worries, I found this kind of fun to work though!
